# Visualise Multiple lines in plotly express plot

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I am currently experimenting with plotly expess graphs to plot multiple sensor measurements.
I have a csv data set which I read with pandas looking a like this (df_full_data):

[data example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brTbc.png)

The data is used within a call back graph where two dropdown fields are used as input to define the year (year_value) and which sensors (hoved) should be shown in the graph.

```
year_data = df_full_data[df_full_data.years == int(year_value)]
filtered_sensor = year_data[year_data['ID'].isin(hoved)]
```

I use then px.line to plot the data.

```
figure = px.line(filtered_sensor, x=filtered_sensor['time'], y=filtered_sensor['water_m'], color=filtered_sensor['ID'], title='Sensor Meting')
```

everything is working fine when one sensorID is selected, but when I select two sensors the data will be shown behind each other. Meaning that first Sensor 58 data will be shown from 01/01/2019 till 31/12/2010, and the x axis will then start again from 01/01/2019 and plot the data of sensor 64.

[plot result with two data sets.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPt7a.png)

I would like to plot the two graphs above each other/ on top of each other, and I guess this has something to do with how I sort or structure my panda table and how plotly will represent it, but I have no Idea how to accomplish this.
Any idea or tips how to change it so the data will be represented above each other like this:

[correct graph example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8n9sk.png)

**Tried**
I have tried to add traces for each sensor with:

```
fig = go.Figure()
for subset_id, subset in year_data.groupby('ID'):
    fig.add_trace(
        px.line(
            subset,
            x=subset['time'],
            y=subset['water_m'],
            color=subset['ID'],
            title=subset_id
        ).data[0]
    )
```

But it still gives me the same behaviour that the sensors are plotted in serie and not parallel to each other.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have a dataframe `df`, with columns: `'id'`, `'time'`,`'air_Pa'`, `'water_m'` and `'year'`, representing times and pressures from some process, with a serial row index. Your `'time'` format is day first, so that a pandas dataframe and plotly graph will see it as a series of strings, not as a time series, and that's why plots from different sensors do not superpose. That's probably why you also need a `'year'` column, otherwise you shoud be able to using `'time'` to slice yearly data. Just try to convert dayfirst datetime column into a valid pandas timestamp:

```
df.time = pandas.to_datetime(df.time,dayfirst = True)
```

Moreover, you can also read from csv already parsing dates dayfirst...

```
df = pd.read_csv('df.csv', dayfirst=True, parse_dates=True)
```

... and now your plots won't superpose.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is to add a second or even third `trace` to your plot.

Snippet from [Documentation](https://plotly.com/python/creating-and-updating-figures/#adding-traces) of plotly express

```
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=[2, 4],
        y=[4, 8],
        mode="lines",
        line=go.scatter.Line(color="gray"),
        showlegend=False)
)
```

Comment: Thank you for you reaction, 
The only thing with adding traces to my plot, is that I don't know beforehand how many traces I should add (as the amount of sensors are picked within the callback is different every time) 

Would you suggest to run the trace within a for loop then so It will automatically add as many traces as selected sensors?

Comment: Usually what I do is to separate out graph generating functions into a different `.py` file. So then I can have parameters as input the function, which can then dynamically add traces in a loop and `return` the figure, to be called in the layout. Hope this helps

Comment: Strangely enough I still get the same behaviour after implementing a trace to my plot, as what I had before and  shown in the earlier posted picture: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPt7a.png)

I added the following code to test the trace behaviour:
`sub2 = year_data[year_data.ID == hoved[1]]`
`fig2 = px.line(sub2, x=sub2['time'], y=sub2['water_m'], color=sub2['ID'])`
`figure.add_trace(fig2.data[0])`

Comment: There are two things here. 1 you need to check if you have the data points for the `x axis` available for both the traces you are plotting. Second, you need to add the trace to the same fig. In your note above, your figure `object` is `fig2`. Then you have added the trace to `figure`. It should be `fig2.add_trace(x=sub2['time'], y=...)`. Also maybe you are looking for a groupby ID column. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62434716/how-to-plot-a-dash-plotly-graph-with-categories-count-on-a-particular-date/62555791#62555791

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()

for subset_id, subset in year_data.groupby('ID'):
    fig.add_trace(
        px.line(
            subset,
            x=subset['time'],
            y=subset['water_m'],
            color=subset['ID'],
            title=subset_id
        )
    )
```

Comment: The proposed piece of code works without any errors when I add .data[0] on the end of fig.add_trace. 

so what you will get is: 
`for subset_id, subset in year_data.groupby('ID'):
    fig.add_trace(
        px.line(
            subset,
            x=subset['time'],
            y=subset['water_m'],
            color=subset['ID'],
            title=subset_id
        ).data[0]
    )`

Unfortunately does dis not solve the problem that each sensor data will be plotted in series instead of parallel to each other.

I have added an foto to original question.